# How to get Specialization name from MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, database

i have such schema  of sities in mongoDB

```
const CitiesSchema =  new Schema({
    name:{ type:String } 
    id:Object.id
});
```

and have such user schema

```
const UserSchema =  new Schema({
    name:           { type:String, default:'' },
    surname:        { type:String, default:'' },
    foreName:        { type:String, default:'' },
    email:          { type:String, default:'', unique:true },
    password:       { type:String, default:'' },
    phone:          { type:String, default:'' },
    role:           { type:String, default:'' },
    profileImg:     { type:String, default:'/images/profile.png' },
    createdAt:      { type:Date, default:Date.now },
    city:           { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Story' }
}, { strict: false });
```

how can i get City name together with user like this :

```
{
    name:'xxxxx',
    surname:'xxxxx',
    city:'xxxxx' // not Object id, but name
    ......
}
```

thanks a lot !!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mongoose [population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) to replace the city key in the result of your query with an object in your cities collection instead of a reference. So if you write your user query like this:

```
User
.findOne({ name: 'Jane' })
.populate('city')
.exec(function (err, user) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  console.log('The user lives in %s', user.city.name);
  // prints "The user's lives in Amsterdam"
});
```

You'll get the city's name in `user.city.name`.

Comment: If you tried this and it's not working, your problem might be that the ref in your User schema points to the Story collection instead of what I assume should be called City or something similar. `city:           { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Story' }`

Comment: And if i need not to find one , but get array of user with populations of necessary fields)

Comment: Should be the same story! Just tack on the same populate method to your user query, like `User.find(...).populate.exec...`